# Mass assignment enter value in guarded field

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, scoped-mass-assignment

Is it possible to fill a guarded field with the ::create method from Elequent models,
If my User model is like so:

```
$guarded=['password','id']
 $fillable=['username']
```

Is it possible to do this?

```
User::create(['username'=>'mynewusername','password'=hash::make($password)])
```

Answer (score 1):

No - you cannot do that.

But you could do this

```
$user = User::create(['username'=>'mynewusername']);
$user->password = Hash::make($password);
$user->save();
```